There is no chance he will/would win - differences in meaning?
Example 1

There is no chance he will win.

Example 2

There is no chance he would win.

What are the differences in meaning?

@MichaelHarvey What about hypotheticals? "If I were to leak what I know, there's no chance he would win." Probably ought to be "...there would be no chance," but "is" is probably also reasonable.

There is no chance he will win strongly implies he will at least actually compete (albeit unsuccessfully), whereas There is no chance he would win strongly implies he won't even compete anyway.

There's not much difference.  But "will" is a simple future. It makes a statement about a future event.  "Would" is used in conditional sentences, and so the second suggests an unspoken condition: "There's no chance he would win if....".  But as the "if" part is unspoken, you'll have to infer it from the context.  That works grammatically, but there are better ways to phrase the condition.
But when talking of the future, all things are uncertain, and so the simple future and the conditional carry very similar information, and the choice is mostly rhetorical.
"Would" can also appear in "future in the past" and "past habits" senses, but those uses of "would" don't fit this sentence (since the main verb "is" is in the present tense)
